# Arithmetic Mean for Continuous Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, means

Arithmetic Mean is defined by:
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i)}{n}
$$
Now, let's define the $x_i$ as, $x_{i+1}-x_{i} = \Delta x$ with $x_1 = a, x_n = b$ where $[a, b]$ is an interval in which $f(x)$ is integrable. Then clearly,
$$x_n = x_1 + (n-1)\Delta x \Rightarrow b = a + (n-1)\Delta x \Rightarrow n = \frac{b-a+\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$

Plugging this value of n into the Arithmetic Mean formula gives:
$$\Rightarrow \bar{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i) \Delta x}{b-a+\Delta x}$$

Setting the limit $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$:
$$
\Rightarrow \bar{x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i)\Delta x}{b - a + \Delta x}
$$
$$\Rightarrow \bar{x} = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{b - a}dx$$

This is how I convince myself why continuous arithmetic mean is defined this way. But I'm still bothered by the fact that, after applying the limit, I actually dismissed the $\Delta x$ in the denominator $b-a+\Delta x$ while still keeping it as $dx$ in the numerator.

What could be a valid argument to dismiss the $\Delta x$ in the denominator? How to prove that the sums $\sum \frac{f(x)\Delta x}{b-a+\Delta x}$ and $\sum \frac{f(x)\Delta x}{b-a}$ are the same for a sufficiently small $\Delta x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aim to prove that a Riemann sum of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{hf\left(a+ih\right)}{\left(b-a\right)+h}$ converges to the same integral regardless of the $+h$ term in the denominator, where $h=\dfrac{b-a}{n}$. Observe that the denominator is independent of the index $i$ and can therefore be separated out of the sum and expanded as a geometric series in $h$. Hence the sum can be written as $\displaystyle \dfrac1{(b-a)+h}S=\frac1{b-a}S+\frac{-h/(b-a)}{b-a}S+\ldots$ The higher order terms vanish as $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you are applying $\Delta x=(b-a)/n.$
Then
$$  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i) \Delta x}{b-a+\Delta x}- \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i) \Delta x}{b-a}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i) (\Delta x)^2}{(b-a+\Delta x) (b-a)}$$
The absolute value of the last expression is less than or equal
$$Mn{(\Delta x)^2\over (b-a)^2}={M\over n}\to 0$$
where $M=\max|f(x)|.$